# Does anyone know if in Android there is similar library to Assets Library Framework in iOS?

Tags: android, video-processing, android-assets

Did you encounter any kind of solution which would allow me to create a movie from picture frames in Android.
This case in iOS is handled by Assets Library Framework, and after my research in Android SDK I need to say there is no similar solution in Android yet.

Do you know any implementation which replicates this feature?

Answer (score 0):

AssetsLibrary Framework allows you to access Video and Photos on iOS.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html

MediaStore in android provides similar functionality
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

Comment: That is true it's providing me access to this resources, the problem which I'm trying to solve is to create from some pictrues on sdCard a video. In iOS I have a direct access to feature which workes. I don't see anything similar in Android for now. One of possible experiments would be using ffmpg tool, but I would prefere something more native...